# Searching similar words in Mysql with android app

Tags: android, mysql, full-text-search, similarity

I have an android application which has search bar for user looks for products. And all informations are stored in Mysql.

When a user search for a product, the results are exactly what user write, but I want to results contain also similar words with considering of may be user wrote incorrect.

I'm using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(product_name) AGAINST('galaxy' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as score FROM product WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST('galaxy' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY score
```

Assume that my table something like that

| id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Galaxy S20 |
| 2 | Galaxy S10 |
| 3 | Playstation |

So if the user enters 'galaxy', the result will be Galaxy S20 and Galaxy S10. It's ok. But If user enters 'galaxt' by mistake, then result will be null. For this situation, I want to detect user's entering and list Galaxy S20 and Galaxy S10 because of user made mistake.

I tried SOUNDEX too, but it didn't what I want.

Someone say could be Levenshtein Distance, but I'm not sure.

So how can I list with similar words? Is it about android side or sql statement?

Comment: i think your question has some merit and (i personally) consider it a valid question, i personally don't think this has anything to do with android, i'd imagine this is something you'd have to implement with your sql, but i could be wrong